# Изменить INCLUDE в make

Tags: linux, gcc, arm

Хочу скомпилировать [cgminer](https://github.com/bitmaintech/cgminer) это приложения для ARM
Выполняю

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-bitmain   CFLAGS="-O2 -Wall  -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/" CC=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc  --host arm --config-cache
```

Выдает в конце

```
Compilation............: make (or gmake)
CPPFLAGS.............:
CFLAGS...............: -O2 -Wall  -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/
LDFLAGS..............:  -lpthread
LDADD................: -ldl -lcurl  compat/jansson-2.9/src/.libs/libjansson.a -lz -lpthread    -lm  -lrt

Installation...........: make install (as root if needed, with 'su' or 'sudo')
prefix...............: /usr/local
```

С виду все ок, но делаю `make`

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls-narrow.h:33:1: error: Б─≤_Float128Б─≥ is not 
supported on this target
__MATHCALL_NARROW (__MATHCALL_NAME (sub), __MATHCALL_REDIR_NAME (sub), 2);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl/curl.h:39,
             from cgminer.c:53:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl/curlrules.h:142:3: error: size of array 
Б─≤__curl_rule_01__Б─≥ is negative
__curl_rule_01__
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl/curlrules.h:152:3: error: size of array 
Б─≤__curl_rule_02__Б─≥ is negative
__curl_rule_02__
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Makefile:932: recipe for target 'cgminer-cgminer.o' failed
make[2]: *** [cgminer-cgminer.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/cj/cgminer-master'
Makefile:1813: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cj/cgminer-master'
Makefile:748: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Почему путь INCLUDE ищет в `x86_64-linux-gnu`, а не `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/` ?
Как изменить?

Comment: По идее, CC и CFLAGS должны писаться в командной строке ПЕРЕД ./configure. Вам это не очевидно и вы пытаетесь кросс-компилировать?..

Comment: Вы, наверное, не понимаете, как работает кросс-компиляция в GNU autotools. Там задаётся три параметра, один из которых система, на которой компилируется, а один — система, для которой компиляция происходит. Суммарно заголовки будут подставлены автоматически. Так что почитайте документацию.